# A use case for retry function?

Tags: ruby

I read this snippet, and I am trying to understand how I can use `retry`, and I am unable to think of a use. How are others using it?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

for i in 1..5
    retry if  i > 2
    puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

Comment: I did not know retry was also available in loops. I've only used it for rescues: Do something rescue the exception, do something different and then retry. Example: http://www.wikidlabs.com/ruby-stuff-use-retry-to-restart-a-begin-rescue-block/

Comment: `retry` worked in loops in 1.8. That functionality disappeared in 1.9 so it only works in `rescue` now. "The Ruby Programming Language" book says: `... In Ruby 1.8, however, retry has another use: it restarts an iterator-based iteration (or any method invocation) from the beginning. This use of the retry statement is extremely rare, and it has been removed from the language in Ruby 1.9. It should, therefore, be considered a deprecated language feature and should not be used in new code.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several use cases. Here's one from the Programming Ruby book

```
@esmtp = true

begin
  # First try an extended login. If it fails because the
  # server doesn't support it, fall back to a normal login

  if @esmtp then
    @command.ehlo(helodom)
  else
    @command.helo(helodom)
  end

rescue ProtocolError
  if @esmtp then
    @esmtp = false
    retry
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

An other common case is the email delivery. You might want to retry the SMTP delivery for N times adding a `sleep` between each retry to avoid temporary issues caused by network connectivity.

Comment: I don't think that is really good...  What if you get a protocol error for the helo method?  Seems to me retry should be used when the thing you are doing again is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it for a module that makes an api call to a 3rd party web api, and so if it fails, I retry 2 more times.